# PHP mail message variables

Tags: php, email

This is most likely a simple fix, I have my php form

```
<?php


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];




$to = "email";
$subject = "Quiz Entries";
$message = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['name'];
$from = "website";
$headers = "From:" . $from;


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Mail Sent.";


?>
```

I want the email message to contain the users email and name, when i declare the variable a second time it just overwrites it so only sends name.

Comment: `$message = $_POST['email'] . " " . $_POST['name']`, the full-stop is the concatenation symbol/operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to concatenate `name` to the message (notice the `.` operator).  In  your code you are just overwriting $message with `$_POST['name']`.

```
$message = $_POST['email'];
$message .= $_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$message = $_POST['email'];
$message .= " ".$_POST['name'];
```

In that way ( `.=` ) you append second variable to first and, obviously, no overwrites will be done